# Dynamically generating controls for angular FormControl

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have the following problem: 
I want to generate a dynamic Form using Angulars `FormControl`. Iterating through `myForm` array (which keeps all the input fields I need) I want to ADD to `this._controls`.. Is there any method I can do this? In my code I'm overwriting `this._controls` with every loop. I'm thankful for every help!

```
private initForm() {
    for (const dat of this.formBuilderService.myForm) {
      if (dat.required) {
        this._controls = ({[dat.bezeichnung]: new FormControl(null, 
           Validators.required)});
      } else {
        this._controls = {[dat.bezeichnung]: new FormControl(null, null)};
      }
    }
    this.form = new VhvFormGroup<FormBuilderModel>(this._controls);
  }
```

Comment: [♪  The documentation is there for you ♪](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add each control with separate key, use formControl name as key, for example you can have `name` property in `dat`

```
private initForm() {
    for (const dat of this.formBuilderService.myForm) {
      if (dat.required) {
        this._controls[dat.name] = ({[dat.bezeichnung]: new FormControl(null, 
           Validators.required)});
      } else {
        this._controls[dat.name] = {[dat.bezeichnung]: new FormControl(null, null)};
      }
    }
    this.form = new VhvFormGroup<FormBuilderModel>(this._controls);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! When I use your code I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined"

Comment: @nwkn try to add default value `{}` for `this._controls` where you declared it

Comment: and make sure you have `name` property in `dat`